# Is there a way to create TemplateRef elements in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to make a schema render component with angular, it depends on dynamic component, just like:

```
class DynamicComponent {
    // ...

    private loadComponent(host: ViewContainerRef, component: Type<any>) {
        const type = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
        host.clear();
        
        return host.createComponent(type);
    }
}
```

in some case, a Component's Input can be TemplateRef element:

```
class SomeComponent {

    @Input() public template: TemplateRef<void>;
}
```

so i want to create TemplateRef element for this case:

```
class DynamicComponent {
    // ...

    private loadComponent(host: ViewContainerRef, component: Type<any>) {
        const type = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
        host.clear();
        const componentRef = host.createComponent(type);

        componentRef.instance.template = ?
    }
}
```

is there any way can do that?

---

**update**

let me introduce the SchemaRenderComponent, it accept json schema and render the ui.

the json schema describe the structure of component:

```js
{
    type: SomeComponent,
    style: {},
    props: {
        template: OtherComponent
    },
    events: {},
}
```

in my design, SomeComponent's Input `template` is a Component in the json schema, and i will dynamic create TemplateRef for it. In html template looks like:

```html
<SomeComponent [template]="template"></SomeComponent>

<ng-template #template>
    <OtherComponent></OtherComponent>
</ng-template>
```

so i have to find a way to create TemplateRef.

(The TemplateRef is rendered by ngTemplateOutlet directive)

Comment: This is a bit vague.. how would the template input be set..? Which parent component does that?

Comment: I have updated the describe, maybe my design is a mistake?